# Track click on whole HTML page with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick, click

i'm trying to track click on html element.

with:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    // action here
});
```

but this thing won't work with iframe , coudn't catch iframe click, or click to selectionbox

http://jsfiddle.net/TYJtc/4/

Comment: Are you trying to track a click on an element inside an iframe or on the iframe element itself?

Comment: Consider using `'body'` or `document` instead.

Comment: @GauravShetty no, i making a tag suggestion like stackoverflow.

Comment: i need to hide tag suggestion when click to other area except tag suggestion zone

Comment: @ThiefMaster Body didn't work too

Comment: didn't work with iframe, selection http://jsfiddle.net/TYJtc/4/

Comment: change title to track click when clicking inside iframe

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the iframe content is of your domain, using jquery 1.7.2 and this should be inside of document ready

http://jsfiddle.net/TYJtc/6/

html

```
<iframe id="myframe" src='/'></iframe>
```

js

```
$('#myframe').contents().find('body').bind('click', function(e) {

   alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: This causes an alert anywhere on the document, not just in the iframe.

Comment: @ErmSo did you even look at the fiddle js? there is an alert for document click because you had that before and then there is the alert for the iframe click. Get rid of the document click if you don't want it

Comment: Sorry! I guess my browser has cached on an earlier revision, I don't have my original document.ready tag in jsfiddle

Comment: @ErmSo appreciated if you check mark my answer as correct if it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your script inside the document.ready function, and change 'html' to document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
     alert("click");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TYJtc/1/

Comment: is the iframe on your own server? if so, place the code inside the iframe

Comment: @EmSo yeb, but that's tiny mce , and i think i can modife their code :( , i only want to make tag suggestion system like stackoverflow. click to blank area, change focus to close tag suggestion, except click on tag suggestion zone.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a div with a high z-index over the iframe. That should intercept all clicks and call the document click handler. The major issue is just that though. It intercepts all clicks so the underlying iframe will not receive any click events.

Comment: yea that will prevent the iframe from being useful but good thought